# MySQL & FK constraints

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, myisam

**Is there any point in defining FK constraints in MyISAM?** MyISAM doesn't enforce referential integrity, right? So maybe there is no point to FK constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although MySQL parses and ignores them on MyISAM tables, I think you should write them for three reasons.

- Preparation: Your code will be ready when MyISAM gets there.
- Documentation: Everybody will know what you intended. Much better than trying to figure out where foreign keys are supposed to go a year from now.
- Insurance: If MyISAM fails you, you can move directly to InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

At the end of second column:

> At a later stage, foreign key constraints will be implemented for
>   MyISAM tables as well.

apparently in mysql 5.0 'latter stage' has not come yet 
constraints are needed as an additional validation